# Why podman generate kube does not create persistent volume claims for volumes?

Tags: kubernetes, docker-compose, minikube, podman, podman-compose

I have a simple docker-compose file:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  auth-service:
    image: <username>/auth-service:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      RUST_LOG: info
      REDIS_HOST: redis-service
      REDIS_PORT: 6379
      RABBITMQ_HOST: rabbitmq-service
      RABBITMQ_PORT: 5672

  redis-service:
    image: redis:latest
    volumes:
      - redis:/data

  rabbitmq-service:
    image: rabbitmq:latest
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: guest
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: guest
```

When I do `podman generate kube` command, I get the following YAML for Redis:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2023-11-26T12:58:11Z"
  labels:
    app: auth-app-redis-service-1-pod
  name: auth-app-redis-service-1-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - redis-server
    image: docker.io/library/redis:latest
    name: auth-app-redis-service-1
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /data
      name: 1005b2fef1c47d55188a90e533bd0f4dca7a201e002db309fffd8367fd356dd5-pvc
  volumes:
  - name: 1005b2fef1c47d55188a90e533bd0f4dca7a201e002db309fffd8367fd356dd5-pvc
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: 1005b2fef1c47d55188a90e533bd0f4dca7a201e002db309fffd8367fd356dd5
```

And it's fine, except volumes. I want to apply it to Minikube, but I can't cause my claim doesn't exist. So why are they generated, and when and how should I apply them? Is it working only for Podman's Kubernetes backend? So, should I remove volumes for the Minikube setup? Appreciate.

UPD_1:

I changed compose to:

```yaml
  redis-service:
    image: redis:latest
    volumes: []

  rabbitmq-service:
    image: rabbitmq:latest
    volumes: []
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: guest
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: guest
```

And restart it, and podman still generates volumes in YAML. That's strange, but it's another topic.

UPD_2:

I get PVC manifests with the following script and am frustrated if this is the only way to achieve this (meaning manual generation). That's strange that podman itself knows that the container has a volume, but doesn't create PVC for it.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p k8s

for service in $(podman compose ps -q); do
    service_name=$(podman inspect --format '{{ index .Config.Labels "com.docker.compose.service" }}' $service)
    
    # Generate Kubernetes YAML for the container
    podman generate kube $service > "k8s/$service_name.yaml"

    # Check if the container has volumes
    volumes=$(podman inspect --format '{{ range .Mounts }}{{ .Source }}{{ end }}' $service)

    if [ -n "$volumes" ]; then
        # Extract the volume name from the path
        volume_name=$(echo "$volumes" | awk -F'/' '{print $(NF-1)}')

        # Generate PVC YAML using 'podman kube' with the extracted volume name
        podman kube generate $volume_name > "k8s/${service_name}_${volume_name}_pvc.yaml"
    fi
done
```

UPD_3 (fantasy):
I expected something like `podman kube generate my-container` or even `podman kube generate my-compose-project` to get all the needed k8s kinds.

Comment: Your Compose file doesn't seem to have a top-level `volumes:` block that declares a `redis` volume (matching the `volumes:` block in the `redis` container).  If you add this declaration, does the generator tool create a PVC for you?

Comment: @DavidMaze, I just override volume and added top-level declaration, YAML changed to pvc with my name, but no pvc kind appeared

Comment: If it makes sense, I do conversion with script below: https://pastebin.com/jTrnXSqU

Comment: Just figured out that direct command to generate pvc kidn works: podman generate kube auth-app_redis